# How to use setState without StatefulWidget?

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart

First of all i know it's not really posible to do it, but I have a problem and I don't know what to do.
I want to use DropDown but it wont change the text without the setState and i cant convert this code to a StatefulWidget. What should i do? The code dosen't reallly matter, but here it is(not the whole code):

```
  Widget buildAboutDialog(
      BuildContext context, _myHomePageState, bool isEdit, Clothes clothes){
    if(clothes != null){
      this.clothes = clothes;
      teCategoryName = clothes.category;
      teBrandName.text = clothes.brand;
      teColorName.text = clothes.color;
      teSizeName.text = clothes.size;
      teQtyName.text = clothes.qty;
    }
   return new AlertDialog(
      title: new Text(isEdit ? 'Edit' : 'Add new Clothes'),
      content: new SingleChildScrollView(
        child: new Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(

              child: Center(
                child: DropdownButton(
                  hint:  Text("Choose Category"),
                  value: teCategoryName,
                  isExpanded: true,
                  onChanged: (newValue){
                    teCategoryName = newValue;
                    **setState(() {
                      teCategoryName = newValue;
                    });**

                  },
                  items: _categorynames.map((location){
                    return DropdownMenuItem(
                      child: new Text(location),
                      value: location,
                    );
                  }).toList(),

                ),
              ),
            ),
```

Comment: `i cant convert this code to a StatefulWidget` That assumption is wrong. You always can. Why do you think you can't?

Comment: I tried it like 5 times, always got some kind of error, this is the full code:
https://gist.github.com/Matelevi12/d3669846e36d84cf3e8750bc8488ac50

Do you think its posible to convert it? I can try it again but i fell like there is something else wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can't.**

The `setState` method updates the widget's state. A `StatelessWidget`, by definition, doesn't have a state to update. So if you want to be able to call `setState`, you need to convert your widget to a `StatefulWidget`. (But yes, any `StatelessWidget` can fairly easily be converted to a `StatefulWidget`.)

Comment: I could convert it, buut i got error and its not woking properly. This is what i get:
E/flutter (14185): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: setState() called in constructor: AddClothesDialog#3e267(lifecycle state: created, no widget, not mounted)
E/flutter (14185): This happens when you call setState() on a State object for a widget that hasn't been inserted into the widget tree yet. It is not necessary to call setState() in the constructor, since the state is already assumed to be dirty when it is initially created.

Comment: @Matelevi12 You can't (and shouldn't) call `setState` on a widget before that widget has been built for the first time. You can get around this if you surround the call to `setState` with `if(mounted) { ... }`.

Comment: Thank you that helped, I dont get an error anymore whitch is great, but still wont change the text.

Comment: @Matelevi12 What text specifically are you talking about?

Comment: If you're talking about the text within the dialog, the reason it won't update is because the dialog widget is its own page with its own state. When you call `setState`, you are updating the state of your local widget, not the state of the dialog. If you want the dialog to update, you need to extract that code into a custom `Dialog` widget and implement it with `StatefulWidget`.

Comment: I did it, but if i choose the text in that StatefulWidget, How should i know what did i picked. So how can i pass tha data back?

Comment: @Matelevi12 If you put the data in as the second parameter to `Navigator.pop`, that value gets returned from `showDialog`, e.g. `var value = await showDialog(...);`